# Failed to import certificates to app service, permissions error

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-appservice

I have a app service, intended to use custom domain. I imported the wild card certificate into the key vault. I then attempted to import the certificate to the app service. All good, passed the validation, but failed with permission error. The key vault was configured at rbac, added the app service to key vault secret user.

I then added the app service to all the roles, still failed with same error.

I read [here](https://dotnetthoughts.net/managing-ssl-certificate-with-azure-keyvault/) and [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/91175) it appears switching back to the access policy will work, but in our case we cannot, as the production key vault already configured to use the rbac model.

What do i do now?? please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate?tabs=apex%2Cportal#authorize-app-service-to-read-from-the-vault), this is not supported:

> Currently, a Key Vault certificate supports only the Key Vault access policy, not RBAC model.

Comment: thanks Thomas, so the workaround is to create another KV just for the use case of certificate store, since I cannot just change the existing production one from rbac to access policy without losing the current setup..